# Python: Adding rows to dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have the following table/dataframe

```
 Year    Period    Amount 
 2010      1         10
 2010      2         5
 2010      4         6
 2010      5         9
 2011      1         10
 2011      3         5
 2011      4         3
```

As you can see, there are missing periods in the period column. I want to add a row for each year with the missing period and an amount of 0. 
I also want the periods to continue to a number that I define, for example 6. 
So the resulting dataframe should be:

```
 Year    Period    Amount 
 2010      1         10
 2010      2         5
 2010      3         0
 2010      4         6
 2010      5         9 
 2010      6         0
 2011      1         10 
 2011      2         0 
 2011      3         5
 2011      4         3
 2011      5         0
 2011      6         0
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far, so we can see where you went wrong? thanks!

Comment: I'm still new to python, I have no idea how to add/join these rows.

Comment: Well, did you read the documentation of pandas? I believe you should try at least _something_, otherwise it is pretty hard to help unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer with running code.

## 1. Set variable for the exemple

```py
In [1]:
data = [[2010, 1, 10], [2010, 2, 5], [2010, 4, 6], [2010, 5, 9], [2011, 1, 10], [2011, 3, 5], [2011, 4, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Year', 'Period', 'Amount'])
df
Out[1]:
    Year    Period  Amount
0   2010    1       10
1   2010    2       5
2   2010    4       6
3   2010    5       9
4   2011    1       10
5   2011    3       5
6   2011    4       3
```

## 2. Create a function to add a row with your conditions

Here the default value of the period is 6, you can change it to whatever you want.

```py
In [2]:
def add_row(df, periods=6):
    years = df.Year.unique().tolist()
    for year in years:
        for i in range(periods):
            
            if len(df[(df['Period']==i+1) & (df['Year']==year)])==0:
                """ If the Period for the year doesn't exist, we add a row"""
                df.loc[-1] = [year, i+1, 0]
                df.index = df.index + 1 

    return df.sort_values(by=['Year', 'Period']).reset_index().drop(axis=1, columns=['index'])
```

## 3. Use the function to make your changes

```py
In [3]: add_row(df)
Out [3]:
    Year    Period  Amount
0   2010    1   10
1   2010    2   5
2   2010    3   0
3   2010    4   6
4   2010    5   9
5   2010    6   0
6   2011    1   10
7   2011    2   0
8   2011    3   5
9   2011    4   3
10  2011    5   0
11  2011    6   0
```

```py
In [4]: add_row(df, periods=10)
Out [4]:
    Year    Period  Amount
0   2010    1   10
1   2010    2   5
2   2010    3   0
3   2010    4   6
4   2010    5   9
5   2010    6   0
6   2010    7   0
7   2010    8   0
8   2010    9   0
9   2010    10  0
10  2011    1   10
11  2011    2   0
12  2011    3   5
13  2011    4   3
14  2011    5   0
15  2011    6   0
16  2011    7   0
17  2011    8   0
18  2011    9   0
19  2011    10  0
```

Comment: @Data_x99 , please take the time to validate this answer if it solves you issue